# Invalid pointer error using google mock

Tags: unit-testing, pointers, googlemock

I'm using Google Mock Framework to perform unit test over a serial port manager class. The class diagram I'm using is

[image]

One of the tests I've prepared in order to test Serial Port Manager is:

```
TEST(SerialPortManagerTest,AllPortsAreClosedAtInit){

MockSerialPort port1;
EXPECT_CALL(port1, IsOpen()).Times(Exactly(1)).WillOnce(Return(false));

MockSerialPort port2;
EXPECT_CALL(port2, IsOpen()).Times(Exactly(1)).WillOnce(Return(false));

MockSerialPort port3;
EXPECT_CALL(port3, IsOpen()).Times(Exactly(1)).WillOnce(Return(false));

SerialPortInterface* port1Ptr=&port1;
SerialPortInterface* port2Ptr=&port2;
SerialPortInterface* port3Ptr=&port3;

MockSerialPortFactory portFactory;
EXPECT_CALL(portFactory, CreateSerialPort(_)).Times(3).
        WillOnce(ReturnPointee(&port1Ptr)).
        WillOnce(ReturnPointee(&port2Ptr)).
        WillOnce(ReturnPointee(&port3Ptr));

SerialPortFactoryInterface* portFactoryPtr=&portFactory;

SerialPortManager* serialPortManager =new SerialPortManager(portFactoryPtr);

EXPECT_FALSE(serialPortManager->GetPort(COM1)->IsOpen());
EXPECT_FALSE(serialPortManager->GetPort(COM2)->IsOpen());
EXPECT_FALSE(serialPortManager->GetPort(COM3)->IsOpen());
}
```

When I execute the test it returns an invalid pointer error:

```
free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfc8d8e4 ***
```

Looking at the problem I found that the error is not returned if I comment the line that deletes serialPortFactory in the SerialPortManager destructor.

```
SerialPortManager::~SerialPortManager() {
    for (int i = 0; i < PORT_COUNT; i++) {
        delete ports[i];
    }
    //delete serialPortFactory;
}
```

¿How can I mock the serialPortFactory without getting this invalid pointer error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because the serial port is being deleted twice in your test.  The first time occurs when the `MockSerialPort` falls out of scope in your test.  The second time occurs inside the destructor for `SerialPortManager`.  If your intention is to have the `SerialPortManager` delete the serial ports, then you must declare the serial ports on the heap within your test:

```
TEST(SerialPortManagerTest,AllPortsAreClosedAtInit){

MockSerialPort* port1 = new MockSerialPort;
EXPECT_CALL(*port1, IsOpen()).Times(Exactly(1)).WillOnce(Return(false));

// Same for the other two serial ports.

MockSerialPortFactory portFactory;
EXPECT_CALL(portFactory, CreateSerialPort(_)).Times(3).
        WillOnce(Return(port1)).
        WillOnce(Return(port2)).
        WillOnce(Return(port3));

// Same as before
}
```